# Pandas column classification

Tags: pandas

Here I am working on a fit bit data set where I have 35 User's Id  column and all other activity  columns  which are of different dates, so now I need to classify all other columns with respective to  user Id column in order to perform my analysis can any one help in this

[image: The image gives an idea about my data set]

Comment: please post a  sample of your dataframe.  You can use `df.to_string()`

Comment: Can you please be a little more elaborate on what you mean by "classify all other columns"

Comment: Cool you need to classify. How? What? Based on what criterion? What is the goal? What have you already tried? What were the results? ...

Comment: my goal is to  merge all common user id as one and then group  the dates and the different activities they perform with their user id and form a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the fuction `groupby()`. You can group by one or more columns, and the perform aggregations per group on the rest of the columns

```py
df.groupby(['id', 'date']).agg([...])
```